# TWTweetComposeViewController crash ios5

Tags: ios5, twitter, crash

On iOS the "protocol" is that

```
        id foo = [[SomeClass alloc] init]
        [foo release]
```

should create an object "foo" with retainCount of 1 so that a release will free it.

The code below on iOS5 will yield a retainCount of 3.

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *twController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
log_trace(@"twController (after construction) retain count %d", [twController   retainCount]);
```

The problem is during a memory warning issued to the app will crash with

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <TWTweetComposeViewController 0x82a3980> for the key path "contentSize" from <UITextView 0x13f2e760> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

I've checked iOS6 beta 1 builds and this behavior is fixed (as is the crash).

Which leads to a question: is there a way to walk around this somehow in iOS5.1 ?

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not convert to ARC and see if the problem gets resolved, if it goes away the crash is your fault not an iOS bug.

Comment: What @phix23 said, retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.  Your error lies elsewhere and that error message gives a pretty good indication where.

Comment: ok, looks like someone was using this class in a non-UI thread. Removing that code fixed the problem. Not presenting it but allocating an instance and then releasing it. Somehow that was a bad thing. Seems to not be an issue on iOS6 beta ... - regardless, does not appear to be an issue anymore.